# HttpError 400 Bad Request - Google Admin Directory API (Python)

Tags: python, api, sdk, directory, admin

I'm having difficulty creating a Google Project as a Service Account. I am using the Admin SDK in Python, specifically the Directory API. I believe I am authenticating correctly but when it comes to calling users.list I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "googleproject.py", line 17, in <module>
userlist = service.users().list().execute(http = http_auth)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 723, in execute
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?alt=json returned "Bad Request">
```

My code is as follows:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build

#----AUTHORISATION----#

client_email = '*****@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
with open('*****.p12') as f:
  private_key = f.read()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user')
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

#--------------------#

service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http = http_auth)
userlist = service.users().list().execute(http = http_auth)
```

I have tried it with and without passing `http = http_auth` as an argument to `execute()`. I've basically followed the example given here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/service_account/tasks.py

I have enabled Admin SDK in the Developers console, as well as added the client id and scope in the Google Apps control panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to fix it! The problem was I wasn't setting the domain in the list argument. So the new code is as follows:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build

#----AUTHORISATION----#

client_email = '*****@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
with open('*****') as f:
  private_key = f.read()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user', sub = 'super-admin@domain.com')
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

#--------------------#

service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http = http_auth)
user = service.users().list(showDeleted = False, domain = 'domain.com').execute()
```